# How to start gvim without terminal?

Tags: c, vim

I'm trying to start gvim using this line:

```
execl("/usr/bin/gvim", "-f", path, (char *)NULL);
```

however I'm getting

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

and I'm not sure how to solve this. I mean, I know that output is not a terminal, that's why I'm using `gvim` instead of just `vim`. It's probably something really obvious, but I just don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you forget to put the program's name as the first parameter of exec, gvim will try to open in terminal mode.

It should be:

```
execl("/usr/bin/gvim", "/usr/bin/gvim",
      "-f", path, (char *)NULL);
```

From the [execl](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) man page:

> **The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename
>   associated with the file being executed**. The list of arguments must be
>   terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions,
>   this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Comment: And gvim is just symlink to vim.. cool, I learn something new every day. Thank you :)